# Excel error when saving as XML spreadsheet

Tags: vba, vsto, excel-2007

I encountered a strange error in an Excel 2007 add-in that seems to be reproducible with a few lines of macro code (**Update**: even without code, see below).

Open a new workbook and add the following code to the first worksheet.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' Suppress macro and overwrite warnings
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "test.xml", XlFileFormat.xlXMLSpreadsheet
End Sub
```

Now each change will save the workbook as an XML spreadsheet file.

However, when I open a second instance of Excel and copy a single cell from there to the auto-saving workbook Excel 2007 crashes. (I have also seen an RPC_E_SERVERFAULT error in a comparable situation.) In Excel 2010 the file is saved as expected.

Any ideas what might be the root cause for this behaviour and how to avoid it?

**UPDATE**

Seems like it's even worse: If I copy data from one Excel (2007) instance to another and save the target workbook as XML spreadsheet Excel crashes. I tried this on two machines, so is this a known bug?